# Multiple environments using WAMP server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, wampserver, test-environments

wondering if you can help me with the following.

I have a new server in my office, with Windows Server 2008 R2, i have 2 developers working here now, i have just installed WAMP on the server and running, i would like that each of the devs to have their own instance in the wamp, i mean if within **www** i have **N** quantity of Projects.

Programmer A gets access to some projects only, also the Databases.

At this point i know how to setup the wamp to be accessed in the LAN using Vhosts, but i have no clue how to setup specific privileges.

Could not find anything on the web on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest another method.

As WAMPServer is intended as a developers tool anyway, you install WAMPServer on each developers PC. You make sure the config on all PC's is the same as the Server version.

For an existing project i.e maintenance/upgrade you give them the source and a database backup. They develop this locally and when its ready you take the source and a database backup to your WAMPServer on the Server.

For a new project, they develop it locally and then when its ready you move the project to the Server.

This would be much simpler and would leave the Server version for UAT or LIVE, whatever you are using it for.

Of course there are better solutions involving source management etc, but as a fairly simple and low maintenance solution, this would work.

Comment: Hello @RiggsFolly thanks for your answer, that's how we were working so far, the server is for local development and storage, we host the sites with an external provider, but the owners of the business want the developers to work in the active directory, is there any way to do this?